# Compact way in Clojure to print a variable number of command line arguments?

Tags: clojure, switch-statement, case, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm a newbie to Clojure.  I think I'm trying to solve this procedurally and there must be a better (more functional) way to do this in Clojure...

The -main function can receive a variable number of 'args'. I would like to print them out but avoid an IndexOutOfBoundsException.  I thought I could mimic Java and use a case fall-through to minimize the code involved, but that didn't work:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (println "There are" (str (count args)) "input arguments.")
  (println "Here are args:" (str args))
  (let [x (count args)]
    (case x
      (> x 0) (do
          (print "Here is the first arg: ")
          (println (nth args 0)))
      (> x 1) (do
          (print "Here is the 2nd arg: ")
          (println (nth args 1)))
      (> x 2) (do
          (print "Here is the 3rd arg: ")
          (println (nth args 2))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(doseq [[n arg] (map-indexed vector arguments)]
  (println (str "Here is the argument #" (inc n) ": " (pr-str arg))))
```

`map-indexes` is like `map` but adds index number in the beginning.
So it goes item by item through arguments, packs index and item into a `vector` and by destructruing index number and item are mapped to `[n arg]`.

Since clojure begins counting from `0`, you use `(inc n)` to begin counting from `1`. `pr-str` is pretty print string. The `str` joins all string components together.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a handy formatting facility in clojure's core library: [cl-format](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format), which is the port of common lisp's format syntax. It includes a nice way to print out collections:

```
(require '[clojure.pprint :refer [cl-format]])

(let [args [:a :b :c :d]]
  (cl-format true "~{here is the ~:r arg: ~a~%~}"
             (interleave (rest (range)) args)))

;; here is the first arg: :a
;; here is the second arg: :b
;; here is the third arg: :c
;; here is the fourth arg: :d
```

some more information about what `format` can do is [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html)

Comment: Can the cl-format library handle a variadic function with a variable number of parameters instead of a set vector?

Comment: sure, there is no difference